# External Azure Stage in Snowflake

Tags: azure, stage

I am not able to Create an external Azure stage in Snowflake.
Error obtained is "Failure using stage area. Cause: [Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of the Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. (Status Code: 403; Error Code: AuthenticationFailed)]".
Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to loading directly from files in Azure containers, Snowflake supports creating named external stages, which encapsulate all of the required information for staging files, including:

- The Azure container where the files are staged.
- The named storage integration object or Azure credentials for the container (if it is protected).
- An encryption key (if the files in the container have been encrypted).
  Named external stages are optional, but recommended when you plan to load data regularly from the same location.

**Reference:-**
To create an Azure external stage please refer this  [Link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-create-stage.html).